# get function not working properly with local storage in JSON string

Tags: javascript, html, json

The get function does not seem to be working properly in my code. I can run it successfully without any errors. My data is going into local storage. But when I try to pull the data out of the local storage it still sending results of null.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

/**
 * A JSON string that holds data. There is no problem with the JSON string
 * @type {String}
  */

    var busSchd = '{"Routes": [{"routeName": "Milledge","stops":[{"Stop 1":"Main Library","Stop 2":"Clarke Central","Stop 3":"Five Points South","Stop 4":"Five Points North","Stop 5":"Waddell"}]},{"routeName": "Orbit","stops":[{"Stop 1":"Main Library","Stop 2":"Clarke Central","Stop 3":"Five Points South","Stop 4":"Five Points North","Stop 5":"Waddell"}]},{"routeName": "East West","stops":[{"Stop 1":"East Campus Deck","Stop 2":"Creswell Hall","Stop 3":"Hull St Deck","Stop 4":"Main Library","Stop 5":"Joe Frank Harris"}]}]}';

    
const load = () => {
    let data = JSON.parse(busSchd);
    console.log("a");
for (var i = 0; i < data.Routes.length;)
     {
         let route = data.Routes[i++];
         let routeStr = route.routeName;
         localStorage.setItem(routeStr, JSON.stringify(route.stops));
      }

};

    const clicked = () => {
     
       var search = document.getElementById("search");
       var results = localStorage.getItem("search");

      if (results === null) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<b>There are no results for that route name.</b>";
      } else {
        var stops = results;
        var output = '';
        for (var key in stops[0]) {
          var output = output + '<b>' + key + '</b> : ' + stops[0][key] + '<br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
      }
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Load Route Data" id="load" onclick="load();">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="search"><input type="button" value="Find Route" id="submit" onclick="clicked();"><br>
  <br><br>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

From quickly looking, there are quite a few issues. But to get you started:

```
var search = document.getElementById("search");
var results = localStorage.getItem("search");
```

Should be:

```
var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
var results = localStorage.getItem(search);
```

Without .value at the end, search is only returning the element and not the user input. In results, putting "search" causes it to look for a storage item called "search" where as you want to search for the input which is stored in the variable search (without quotes);
Also, script tag should go before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your `localStorage` assignments are to the `routeStr` variable:

```
localStorage.setItem(routeStr, JSON.stringify(route.stops));
```

But your retrieval is from the `.search` property:

```
var results = localStorage.getItem("search");
```

Because you never assign to `localStorage.search`, `results` is always null. Try retrieving from the *route name typed into the input instead*. You also need to fix the function that retrieves the stop information from `localStorage`.

Because stack snippets don't support `localStorage`, check out the demo on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5muvh4gj/

```js
var busSchd = '{"Routes": [{"routeName": "Milledge","stops":[{"Stop 1":"Main Library","Stop 2":"Clarke Central","Stop 3":"Five Points South","Stop 4":"Five Points North","Stop 5":"Waddell"}]},{"routeName": "Orbit","stops":[{"Stop 1":"Main Library","Stop 2":"Clarke Central","Stop 3":"Five Points South","Stop 4":"Five Points North","Stop 5":"Waddell"}]},{"routeName": "East West","stops":[{"Stop 1":"East Campus Deck","Stop 2":"Creswell Hall","Stop 3":"Hull St Deck","Stop 4":"Main Library","Stop 5":"Joe Frank Harris"}]}]}';


window.load = () => {
  let data = JSON.parse(busSchd);
  console.log("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.Routes.length;) {
    let route = data.Routes[i++];
    let routeStr = route.routeName;
    localStorage.setItem(routeStr, JSON.stringify(route.stops));
  }

};

window.clicked = () => {
  var search = document.getElementById("search");
  var results = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(search.value));
  if (results === null) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<b>There are no results for that route name.</b>";
    return;
  }
  const output = Object.entries(results[0]).reduce((a, [stopNum, stopName]) => (
    a + '<b>' + stopNum + '</b> : ' + stopName + '<br>'
  ), '');
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Load Route Data" id="load" onclick="load();">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="search"><input type="button" value="Find Route" id="submit" onclick="clicked();"><br>
<br><br>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to correct this without changing my else statement and creating const output?

Comment: I prefer early returns because they cut down on indentation hell, but if you want to use `else`, that's fine - just add `else {` after the `}`